# Adding date column from a variable value to Spark Dataframe

Tags: python, pyspark

I have a Spark Dataframe as below and I am trying to add a new date column from a variable but gives an error.

jsonDF.printSchema()

```
root
 |-- Data: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- Record: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- FName: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- LName: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- Address: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- Applicant: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- Id: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- Type: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- Option: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- Location: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- Town: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- IsActive: boolean (nullable = true)
 |-- Id: string (nullable = true)
```

Tried both the ways -

```
var_date='2019-07-15'

jsonDF.withColumn('my_date',to_date(var_date,'yyyy-MM-dd'))

jsonDF.select(to_date(var_date,'yyyy-MM-dd')).alias('my_date')
```

But I get an error

```
An error occurred while calling o50.withColumn.
: org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve '`2019-07-15`' given input columns: [Data, Id];;
'Project [Data#8, Id#9, to_date('2019-07-15, Some(yyyy-MM-dd)) AS my_date#213]
+- Relation[Data#8, Id#11] json

An error occurred while calling o50.select.
: org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve '`2019-07-15`' given input columns: [Data, Id];;
'Project [to_date('2019-07-15, Some(yyyy-MM-dd)) AS to_date(`2019-07-15`, 'yyyy-MM-dd'#210]
```

Kindly help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to official documentation, [`to_date`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.to_date) take a column as parameter. Therefore, it is trying to get a column named `2019-07-15`.

You have to convert your value to be a column first, then apply your function.

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

var_date='2019-07-15'
jsonDF.select(F.to_date(F.lit(var_date),'yyyy-MM-dd').alias('my_date'))
```

Another way to do it, use directly the python `datetime`:

```py
import datetime
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

var_date=datetime.date(2019,7,15)
jsonDF.select(F.lit(var_date).alias('my_date'))
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
from datetime import datetime
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

var_date='2019-07-15'

jsonDF.withColumn('my_date',F.lit(datetime.strptime(var_date, '%Y-%m-%d').date()))
```

Comment: Any textual explanation with the code will be helpful. :)